# How to get pointy cone of light in volumetric object

Tags: lighting, volumetrics

I'm following this short tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JzCkohRpRQU

In it, his cone of light has a very sharp beginning of the cone, but mine starts off very round. Could this be because of a difference between the Blender versions? I'm pretty sure I copied all the settings like density and cone size.

My blend file: https://pasteall.org/blend/5a732eea0e9c420b8d4175ae6138e0a3

Here's the comparison, his vs mine:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lower down the light *Radius* value. I think it was the *Size* value in the version he uses.

[image]

Comment: Wow completely overlooked that one..thanks